# Can't establish a ROS2 network

Tags: linux, networking, ros, ros2

I'm starting working with ROS2 (currently in alpha7 state). For this I build up a small network with an Raspberry Pi (Raspbian Jessie) connected to an router via LAN and an host PC (Ubuntu Gnome 16.04) connected to the same router via WLAN. Inside the host are  some virtual machines (using VirtualBox) installed with Debian Jessie and connected via a bridged network (wlp4s0). I can also use `ping`, `ssh` and `scp` between all my machines (Rasp, Host, VMs).

I found that the Rasp doesn't connect to the VM's but the VM's are in contact to each other. So I can send messages between the VM's. But a talker-listener-connection between the Rasp and the VM's doesn't work.

Can anyone give me some suggestions to find out what the reason is to this behaviour?

---

I do some studies using the talker and listener from the sources (alpha7).:
(all ros users are on virtual machines)

### Talker on Raspberry Pi

```
pi:bin$ export OSPL_URI=file:///usr/etc/opensplice/config/ospl.xml
pi:bin$ ./talker

  > pi@192.168.1.40
  > pi:bin$ export OSPL_URI=file:///usr/etc/opensplice/config/ospl.xml
  > pi:bin$ ./listener                                  > yes
  > pi:bin$ ./listener__rmw_opensplice_cpp              > yes
  > pi:bin$ ./listener__rmw_fastrtps_cpp                > yes after restarting talker
  > pi:bin$ ./listener_best_effort                      > yes
  > pi:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_opensplice_cpp  > yes
  > pi:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_fastrtps_cpp    > yes

  > ros@192.168.1.20
  > ros:bin$ export OSPL_URI=file:///usr/etc/opensplice/config/ospl.xml
  > ros:bin$ ./listener                                 > no
  > ros:bin$ ./listener__rmw_opensplice_cpp             > no
  > ros:bin$ ./listener__rmw_fastrtps_cpp               > no
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort                     > no
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_opensplice_cpp > no
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_fastrtps_cpp   > no
```

---

```
pi:bin$ export OSPL_URI=file:///usr/etc/opensplice/config/ospl.xml
pi:bin$ ./talker__rmw_opensplice_cpp

  > pi@192.168.1.40
  > pi:bin$ export OSPL_URI=file:///usr/etc/opensplice/config/ospl.xml
  > pi:bin$ ./listener                                  > yes after restarting talker
  > pi:bin$ ./listener__rmw_opensplice_cpp              > yes
  > pi:bin$ ./listener__rmw_fastrtps_cpp                > no
  > pi:bin$ ./listener_best_effort                      > yes
  > pi:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_opensplice_cpp  > yes
  > pi:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_fastrtps_cpp    > yes

  > ros@192.168.1.20
  > ros:bin$ export OSPL_URI=file:///usr/etc/opensplice/config/ospl.xml
  > ros:bin$ ./listener                                 > no
  > ros:bin$ ./listener__rmw_opensplice_cpp             > no
  > ros:bin$ ./listener__rmw_fastrtps_cpp               > no
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort                     > no
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_opensplice_cpp > no
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_fastrtps_cpp   > no
```

---

```
pi:bin$ export OSPL_URI=file:///usr/etc/opensplice/config/ospl.xml
pi:bin$ ./talker__rmw_fastrtps_cpp

  > pi@192.168.1.40
  > pi:bin$ export OSPL_URI=file:///usr/etc/opensplice/config/ospl.xml
  > pi:bin$ ./listener                                  > yes
  > pi:bin$ ./listener__rmw_opensplice_cpp              > yes
  > pi:bin$ ./listener__rmw_fastrtps_cpp                > yes after restarting talker
  > pi:bin$ ./listener_best_effort                      > yes
  > pi:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_opensplice_cpp  > yes
  > pi:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_fastrtps_cpp    > yes

  > ros@192.168.1.20
  > ros:bin$ export OSPL_URI=file:///usr/etc/opensplice/config/ospl.xml
  > ros:bin$ ./listener                                 > no
  > ros:bin$ ./listener__rmw_opensplice_cpp             > no
  > ros:bin$ ./listener__rmw_fastrtps_cpp               > no
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort                     > no
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_opensplice_cpp > no
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_fastrtps_cpp   > no
```

### Talker on Virtual Machine

```
ros@192.168.1.20
ros:bin$ export OSPL_URI=file:///usr/etc/opensplice/config/ospl.xml
ros:bin$ ./talker

  > ros@192.168.1.21
  > ros:bin$ export OSPL_URI=file:///usr/etc/opensplice/config/ospl.xml
  > ros:bin$ ./listener                                 > yes
  > ros:bin$ ./listener__rmw_opensplice_cpp             > yes
  > ros:bin$ ./listener__rmw_fastrtps_cpp               > yes after restarting talker
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort                     > yes
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_opensplice_cpp > yes
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_fastrtps_cpp   > yes

  > pi@192.168.1.40
  > pi:bin$ export OSPL_URI=file:///usr/etc/opensplice/config/ospl.xml
  > pi:bin$ ./listener                                  > no
  > pi:bin$ ./listener__rmw_opensplice_cpp              > no
  > pi:bin$ ./listener__rmw_fastrtps_cpp                > no
  > pi:bin$ ./listener_best_effort                      > no
  > pi:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_opensplice_cpp  > no
  > pi:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_fastrtps_cpp    > no
```

---

```
ros@192.168.1.20
ros:bin$ export OSPL_URI=file:///usr/etc/opensplice/config/ospl.xml
ros:bin$ ./talker__rmw_opensplice_cpp

  > ros@192.168.1.21
  > ros:bin$ export OSPL_URI=file:///usr/etc/opensplice/config/ospl.xml
  > ros:bin$ ./listener                                 > yes
  > ros:bin$ ./listener__rmw_opensplice_cpp             > yes
  > ros:bin$ ./listener__rmw_fastrtps_cpp               > yes
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort                     > yes
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_opensplice_cpp > yes
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_fastrtps_cpp   > yes

  > pi@192.168.1.40
  > pi:bin$ export OSPL_URI=file:///usr/etc/opensplice/config/ospl.xml
  > pi:bin$ ./listener                                  > no
  > pi:bin$ ./listener__rmw_opensplice_cpp              > no
  > pi:bin$ ./listener__rmw_fastrtps_cpp                > no
  > pi:bin$ ./listener_best_effort                      > no
  > pi:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_opensplice_cpp  > no
  > pi:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_fastrtps_cpp    > no
```

---

```
ros@192.168.1.20
ros:bin$ export OSPL_URI=file:///usr/etc/opensplice/config/ospl.xml
ros:bin$ ./talker__rmw_fastrtps_cpp

  > ros@192.168.1.20
  > ros:bin$ export OSPL_URI=file:///usr/etc/opensplice/config/ospl.xml
  > ros:bin$ ./listener                                 > yes after restarting talker
  > ros:bin$ ./listener__rmw_opensplice_cpp             > yes
  > ros:bin$ ./listener__rmw_fastrtps_cpp               > yes after restarting talker
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort                     > yes
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_opensplice_cpp > yes
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_fastrtps_cpp   > yes

  > ros@192.168.1.21
  > ros:bin$ export OSPL_URI=file:///usr/etc/opensplice/config/ospl.xml
  > ros:bin$ ./listener                                 > yes
  > ros:bin$ ./listener__rmw_opensplice_cpp             > yes
  > ros:bin$ ./listener__rmw_fastrtps_cpp               > yes after restarting talker
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort                     > yes
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_opensplice_cpp > yes
  > ros:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_fastrtps_cpp   > yes

  > pi@192.168.1.40
  > pi:bin$ export OSPL_URI=file:///usr/etc/opensplice/config/ospl.xml
  > pi:bin$ ./listener                                  > no
  > pi:bin$ ./listener__rmw_opensplice_cpp              > no
  > pi:bin$ ./listener__rmw_fastrtps_cpp                > no
  > pi:bin$ ./listener_best_effort                      > no
  > pi:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_opensplice_cpp  > no
  > pi:bin$ ./listener_best_effort__rmw_fastrtps_cpp    > no
```

Comment: While a well documented problem, this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites  http://superuser.com OR http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ . Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Comment: At the moment I'm not sure, if it is a programming question or more related to a bad system set up. This post give only the results of the code. I hope someone can direct me the right way.